# Making each element be a random number in a LinkedList

Tags: java, random, collections, linked-list, element

Premise:
Add 25 random numbers from 0-100 to a LinkedList. Output the list as is, output the list sorted,  output the sum of the numbers from the elements, and output the average of the numbers from the elements.

I believe I have completed all steps except my list produces the same number within each of the 25 elements, albeit random each time the program is run.

(i.e)
Unsorted List: [20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20]
Sorted List: [20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20]

The desired outcome for me is to have all of those numbers be random.

Here is the code I used:

```
//min and max range
    int min = 0;
    int max = 100;

    //Instance of random
    Random rand = new Random();
    int insertRand = min + rand.nextInt(max);
    int i;
    int sum = 0;

    //Instantiation of my LinkedList
    List<Integer> listA = new LinkedList<>();


    //For loop to add 25 numbers to the linkedList
    for (i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        listA.add(insertRand);
    }

    //"for" loop to gain the sum of the list
    for (int j = 0; j < listA.size(); j++) {
        sum += listA.get(j);
    }
```

Comment: Your code only calls `rand.nextInt()` once.

Comment: you assign the `rand.nextInt()` value only once to a variable and keep adding it to the `listA`

Comment: Thank you guys, took me a minute to understand what you meant. I moved the call of rand.nextInt() into the for loop instead of being outside of it and it worked perfectly. thank you all for you assistance.

Comment: Why do you emphasize the `LinkedList` so much? It seems, your task is not related to the actual type of the `List` at all. The only place where it matters, is your last index based loop, which is horribly inefficient when the list is a `LinkedList`, yet another reason to use a straight-forward `for(Integer value: listA) sum += value;`  instead of implementing the iteration logic manually.